# Django favicon.ico in the root directory of the site

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

i can put my favicon in STATIC dir (STATIC_URL = '/static/') - it work.
It work in html:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/marketability/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/marketability/favicon.ico">
```

It work in urls.py as Redirect:

```
urlpatterns = [...
...
   path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/marketability/favicon.ico', permanent=True))
]
```

but if i put favicon.ico in root - /patterns/ it does`t work:

- not work
and

```
urlpatterns = [...
...
   path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/favicon.ico', permanent=True))
] - not work
```

???

I not want use urls.py as RedirectView becouse it return 301 code. The external service (search system) need 200 Ok code of site`s favicon.

directory structure:

```
-myproject
 -myproject
  -marketability
    -patterns
     "..."
     "..."
     "favicon.ico"
     "index.html"
    -static
     -marketability
      "..."
      "..."
      "favicon.ico"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Django is not supposed to serve static files on prod. On of the options is to remove all these patterns and put your file wherever you want on prod server and point nginx/apache config directly to your favicon.